# Посчитать количество строк в функции

Tags: c++, строки, функции

Можно ли как-то узнать, сколько строчек в функции? Возможно, рекурсивно посчитать все строчки для всех вызываемых подфункций. Надо подобное поведение:

```
if (lines(&foo) > 100500) {
  // запускаем в отдельном потоке или процессе
} else {
  // просто вызываем
}
```

Comment: В общем случае невозможно сказать, сколько в данном вызове функции потребуется производительности процессора, памяти, дискового пространства и прочих вычислительных ресурсов. Это, кстати, сильно осложняет построение планировщиков даже в гомогенных и особенно в гертерогенных вычислительных средах.

Answer (score 4):

Простите, не вобьюсь в комметрарий...

Сколько строк, например, в функции `factorial`:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    // Аккумулятор
    int r = 1;
    // Цикл по всем цислам 1..n
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        // Вычисляем произведение
        r = r * i;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Двенадцать? Или одна?

```
int factorial(int n) { int r = 1; for(int i = 1; i <= n; r*=i++); return r; }
```

А как вы оцените строки вызываемых *системных* функций?

Да и что за критерий - количество строк. Как будто быстрая сортировка в 200 строк будет работать дольше сортировки выбором в 20 строк для, скажем, миллионного массива.

Убедил в... гм... несостоятельности вашей идеи?

Comment: Ну я сомневаюсь что 200 строк адекватные люди будут пихать в 1... А как вы предлагаете тогда оценить скорость без запуска функции?

Comment: Заочно - абсолютно никак. В лучшем случае - оценка сложности алгоритма... А так - измерениями, измерениями, измерениями. Кстати, у вас вообще не учитывается, для каких входных данных работаем - а это **крайне** важно.